My IP is probably blocked
I have ordered new dedicated server and on that server I always get timeout using wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/
My IP is probably blocked because it's listed as bad neighborhood on some websites.
Who can I contact to unlock my IP address on public solana RPC ?

Any specific reason you want to use a public endpoint? Why not use a node provider? Most provide free starter plans eg https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-solana/
